# insert date ad time in prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put time and date in my prepare statement to insert current time in mysql database .I was using NOW() , but it's not working . my codes so far :
........

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $statement = $connection->prepare("
        INSERT INTO request(type, date_time) 
        VALUES (:type, NOW())
    ");
    $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':type' =>  $_POST["type"],
            ':date_time'    =>  'NOW()'
           )
        ); 
    }       ..........
```

In my form , the input for date and time is :

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('F j, Y, g:i a'); ? 
   >" name="date_time">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
':date_time' => 'NOW()'
```

from the array of parameters. `NOW()` isn't an input parameter coming from outside the query, it's a native SQL function so it doesn't need parameterising.